# adding secondary sub-board to pin-out header

Tags: pinout

Possibly a very basic question, but I am trying to add a secondary sub-board (receiver) to a micro controller for roller shutter door.

The control board already has a right angle 6-way pinout with 2.54mm pitch. This connects directly into the existing sub-board (receiver).

What I would like to do is to somehow passthrough the pinout to another receiver with the same pinout using simple wires.

The image below shows the current state with the purple existing board connected directly to the right angle pin-out from the control board. The new board is in blue, however they can be swapped around. The order doesn't matter.

My question is: how can I connect a secondary board (shown in blue) to the existing pins? I can't access the pins directly as there are plugged in. I'm guessing I would need some kind of pass-through device or splitter.

[image: diagram of current state and desired]

[image: existing right angle pin-out]

EDIT: Would the below configuration work on a stripboard?

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome. This is a question & answer site, so you must ask a question! (please do so by editing your post!)

Comment: I understand correctly, though: your board is blue in your drawing, and the existing sub-board is violet? Also, would it be possible for the blue and the violet board to swap places?

Comment: yes you understood correctly :) the two boards could in theory be swapped... but I'm not sure what this would achieve? Essentially the two boards would be powered by the same 12v pin, connect to the same GND pin and send power to the same control pin independently.

Comment: I think you should add that info (can be swapped) to the question, it's helpful for answers :)

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way would be soldering wires on each pin. Use only single strand (monolithic) wires.
You can make use of prototype board, cut to desired size, to solder a female connector and a male connector in the appropriate direction to connect the original boards and then add the wires to the secondary sub-board. It will look more solid. But maybe not necessary.

Note that there is no garantee that the secondary sub-board will be recognized by the system or will work properly. But that already another topic.

Comment: OP specifically said soldering was out of question. (before the edit)

Comment: Where did he say that? According to his drawing it should be possible. Thought a picture would help.

Comment: as said, in [an earlier revision](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/485040/1), which is why I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks. If I have 6x1 row pins, I could use a proto board with the same dimensions, solder on a male and female connector to act as a pass through and have the cables soldered in between? 

On your second topic, its a simple garage remote receiver.  It only has V+, GND, and OSC pins. Having multiple receivers shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes, you just need three rows of holes. (unless you want to add some extra components like led indicators)

Comment: Are there prototype boards that has the same dot pitch (2.54mm) as the pins so I can simply have the following design? Row1=female input pins Row2=wire out to secondary sub-board Row3=male output pins to existing sub-board. The on the rear, just solder down the colums?

Comment: Yes: most (if not every) prototype board on sale on the internet or in electronic stores have holes pitch of 2.54mm. They sell borad of diffrent sizes. Some are double faced (usualy green) other are single faced (you can solder only on one side, these are usualy brown). You are lucky the original board has 2.54mm pitch. On single sided board, put insert the headers from the non-solderable side and solder on the other side. Add flux before soldering. Buy more than one sample in case you have to redo it. It's very difficult to remove headers once they are soldered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your suggested man in the middle board would work, physically. As your diagram shows, you just need a 0.1" /2.54mm female header with extended leads (aka a stacking header) for the first board and some regular male headers for the top.

Without knowing what the boards actually are we cant say that the stacking would work though. Power would, but we cant say for sure for the oscillator pin or what the other 3 pins do at all.